# Retrieve values from the database with jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I need to extract the data "FechaCaducidad" from the grid "FarmacoGrid" to store it in an auxiliary variable "fechaCadAux". I tried to do it several different ways but have not been successful.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#FarmacoGrid").jqGrid({
    url: '@Url.Action("Load", "Farmaco")',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    autowidth: true,
    altRows: true,
    altclass: 'grid-alt-row',
    rowNum: @(ViewBag.PageSize * (ViewBag.PageIndex + 1)),
    colNames: ['NomFarmaco', 'Cantidad', 'FechaCaducidad', 'FechaPedido','FechaReposicion', '', '', '', ''],
    colModel: [
        { index: 'NomFarmaco', name: 'NomFarmaco', sortable: true, resizable: false },
        { index: 'Cantidad', name: 'Cantidad', sortable: true, resizable: false },
        { index: 'FechaCaducidad', name: 'FechaCaducidad', sortable: true, resizable: false },
        { index: 'FechaPedido', name: 'FechaPedido', sortable: true, resizable: false },
        { index: 'FechaReposicion', name: 'FechaReposicion', sortable: true, resizable: false },
        { name: 'imagen', sortable: false, classes: 'grid-cell-imagen', resizable: false },
        { name: 'fechaCadAux', sortable: false, classes: 'grid-cell-fechaCadAux', resizable: false },
        { name: 'fechaHoyAux', sortable: false, classes: 'grid-cell-fechaHoyAux', resizable: false },
        { name: 'edit', sortable: false, classes: 'grid-cell-edit', resizable: false },         
    ],
    gridComplete: 
        function(){ 
            var ids = jQuery("#FarmacoGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
            for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++)
            { 
                var rowId = ids[i];
                var fechaCadAux = $("#FarmacoGrid"+FechaCaducidad).val();
                var fechaHoyAux = Date.parse(new Date());
                var imagenHtml = imagenHtml = '<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/verde.png")"/>';
                var editHtml = '<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Farmaco")/' + rowId + '" title="@Resources.Shared.Edit"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/CRUD/edit.png")"/></a>';
                var deleteHtml = '<a href="#" onclick="return DeleteGridItem(\'FarmacoGrid\', \'@Url.Action("Delete", "Farmaco")\', \'' + rowId + '\')" title="@Resources.Shared.Delete"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/CRUD/delete.png")"/></a>';
                $("#FarmacoGrid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { imagen: imagenHtml, "fechaCadAux": fechaCadAux, "fechaHoyAux": fechaHoyAux, "edit": editHtml, "delete": deleteHtml}); 
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my own question is:

```
var fechaCadAux = jQuery("#FarmacoGrid").jqGrid('getRowData',rowId).FechaCaducidad;
```